# Printing out nodes in a disjoint-set data structure in linear time

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, clrs, disjoint-sets, union-find

I'm trying to do this exercise in Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et al that has to do with the Disjoin Set data structure:

> Suppose that we wish to add the operation `PRINT-SET(x)`, which is given
>   a node `x` and prints all the members of `x`'s set, in any order. Show how
>   we can add just a single attribute to each node in a disjoint-set
>   forest so that `PRINT-SET(x)` takes *time linear in the number of members
>   of `x`'s set*, and the asymptotic running times of the other operations
>   are unchanged. Assume that we can print each member of the set in O(1)
>   time.

Now, I'm quite sure that the attribute needed is a *tail pointer*, so it can keep track of the children.

Since the disjoint set structure already has a parent attribute, `find-set(x)` can easily print out nodes going in one direction. But now, having a tail pointer, let's us go the other direction as well.

However, I'm not sure how I would write the algorithm to do this. If anyone could help me out in pseudocode, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Union-Find: retrieve all members of a set efficiently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055236/union-find-retrieve-all-members-of-a-set-efficiently)

Answer (score 15):

Each node should have a `next` pointer to the next node in the set it is in. The nodes in a set should form a *circular linked list*.

When a singleton set is first created, the node's `next` pointer points to itself.

When you merge set with node `X` and set with node `Y` (and you've already checked that those sets are different by normalizing to set representatives), you merge the circular linked lists, which you can do by simply swapping `X.next` and `Y.next`; so this is a `O(1)` operation.

To list all the elements in the set containing node `X`, traverse the circular linked list starting from `X`.