# Union-Find: retrieve all members of a set efficiently

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, union-find

I'm working with an `union-find` algorithm. In the first part of my program, the algorithm computes a partition of a big set `E`.

After that, I want to retrieve all the members of the set `S`, which contains a given node `x`.

Until now, naively, I was testing membership of all elements of `E` to the set `S`. But yesterday I was reading "Introduction to Algorithms" (by CLRS, 3rd edition, ex. 21.3-4), and, in the exercises, I found that:

> Suppose that we wish to add the operation `PRINT-SET(x)`, which is
>   given a node `x` and prints all the members of `x`'s set, in any order.
>   Show how we can add just a single attribute to each node in a
>   disjoint-set forest so that `PRINT-SET(x)` takes time linear in the
>   number of members of `x`'s set, and the asymptotic running times of the
>   other operations are unchanged.

"linear in the number of members of `x`'s set" would be a great improvement for my problem! So, I'm trying to solve this exersice... and after some unsuccessful tries, I'm asking help on Stack Overflow!

Comment: hint: the attribute is the list of elements pointing to that node.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing out nodes in Disjoint Set in linear time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945058/printing-out-nodes-in-disjoint-set-in-linear-time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that union-find is implemented as upside-down tree, where for each set S = {v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>, ..., v<sub>n</sub>}, you have v<sub>n - 1</sub> edges, that ultimately have the same root (or *sink*).

Now, whenever you add an edge (v<sub>i</sub>, v<sub>j</sub>) to this tree, add another edge (using the new attribute) (v<sub>j</sub>, v<sub>i</sub>). And when you remove a node, remove the attribute as well.

Note that the new *edge* is separated from the old one. You use it *only* when printing all elements in a set. And modify it whenever any *original* edge is modified in the original algorithm.

Note that this attribute is actually a list of nodes, but the total number of elements in all lists combined is still *n - 1*.

This will give you a second tree, but not *upside down*. Now, using the root, and doing some tree-traversal (using e.g. [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)), you can print all elements.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to write another algorithm without the use of lists (it is somewhat more convenient to use with my programming language, i.e. ANSI-C).

I did that with the help of

> [Printing out nodes in a disjoint-set data structure in linear time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945058).

I found this thread after my first post, my apologies.

In pseudo-code (not yet tested) :

```
MAKE-SET(x)
    x.p = x
    x.rank = 0
    x.link = x        # Circular linked list

UNION(x,y)
    sx = FIND-SET(x)
    sy = FIND-SET(y)
    if sx != sy
        LINK(sx, sy)

LINK(x,y)
    temp = y.link     # Concatenation
    y.link = x.link   # of the two
    x.link = temp     # circular lists
    if x.rank > y.rank
        y.p = x
    else x.p = y
         if x.rank == y.rank
             y.rank = y.rank + 1

FIND-SET(x)
    if x != x.p
        x.p = FIND-SET(x.p)
    return x.p

PRINT-SET(x)
    root = x
    PRINT(x)
    while x.link != root
        x = x.link
        PRINT(x)
```

Comment: Your solution after slight modification helped me to solve Feature-Toggles test grouping problem.  (Test in the same group should never have a conflicting state of Feature Toggle when executed against the same Test environment).